# Include an image in title page using powerdot

Tags: graphics, positioning, powerdot

I want to include an image at the center of the title page of my `powerdot` presentation. Incidentally, I want the same image to appear as a logo on all the other slides (positioned bottom centre), except on the title page. How do I achieve this? So far I did the following, which did not work:

```
     \title{Hardware Evaluation}
     \author{\bf{Priya} }
     \titlegraphic{\includegraphics[scale=1.0]{Logo.eps}}

    \pdsetup{
    palette=Sea,
    randomdots,
    dprop={dotstyle=ocircle,linewidth=.01pt},
    dmindots=5,dmaxdots=5,
    dminsize=100pt,dmaxsize=200pt,
    dbright=50,
    logohook=c,
    logopos={.500\slidewidth,.060\slideheight},
    logocmd={\includegraphics[scale=.03]{Logo.eps}}
   }
```

Can someone help me place Logo.eps as a centre image on the title slide and as a logo (bottom centre) on the remainder slides.
Thank You.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so] site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: To provide an answer here we'll need a minimal example, which is lacking. Please edit one in and request reopening.